# Magento 2: Use Custom Variable in Layout File

Tags: magento2, module, layout, blocks, custom

We can use Magento default variables in layout file using

```
<item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}</item>
```

I would like to create one variable in Block File & Use it. Like

```
protected function _prepareLayout() {
    parent::_prepareLayout();

    $this->myVar = 'google.com';

    return $this;
}
```

In layout file

```
<item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{myVar}}</item>
```

Can i define & access it or i have to manage through Controller file?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it's possible.

What you can do first is add a protected variable to your block class:

```
protected $_myVar;
```

Then you can define a public method to retrieve this variable:

```
public function getMyVar()
{
     return $this->_myVar;
}
```

Then in your controller action method you can do the following:

```
$resultLayout = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
$block = $resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock('block.name');
$myVar = $block->getMyVar();
```

Please note that you'll have to replace `block.name` with the name of the block declared in your layout.

Comment: If i have 5-10 variables then i have to create each individual function?

Comment: @MikeSmith it's up to you. You can also declare one single function that returns an array that contains all your variables.

Comment: Ok got it. Instead of Controller file Can i define in Block file `app\code\Custom\Module\Block\Index.php`?

Comment: @MikeSmith I'm not too sure. It will only work if the layout has been loaded and if you can access which is usually done via the action classes

Comment: Why i'm asking so i can save that controller 3 Lines

Comment: @MikeSmith the controller has access to the layout you can add those lines to the `execute()` method of your controller class